# Is the page after the title page numbered page 1 or page 2 in MLA7?

Tags: academic-writing, mla

When writing a paper in MLA7 with a title page as the first page, would the second page of the document be numbered as such, or would it be numbered as page 1?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MLA. Is the style written down anywhere? Is it unclear about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In most citation systems the title page is not counted in the page numbers. Try Purdue Owl for more reliable resources. They have a fairly extensive resouces section.